# Carroll statement about the microstates of black hole to be only one

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, statistical-mechanics, black-holes

In his GR book, Carroll states following in the chapter- 6 (More general black holes)

> Usually, we like to associate the entropy of a system with the logarithm of the number of accessible quantum states. There is, therefore, some tension between this concept and the no-hair theorem, which indicates that there are very few possible states for a black hole of fixed charge, mass and spin (**only one, in fact**)

What I'm able to understand to get from the above statement is following: since we need only few parameters (called hair) of black holes to describe their properties (due to Einstein's field equation). We're lead to the situation where we have only one configuration, so the one quantifier.

If I take a system other than black hole, say our solar system, and we use EFE, if I am somehow provided with $T_{\mu\nu}$ then I can solve $g_{\mu \nu}$ using EFE but wouldn't it will lead to same situation of only one state in the configuration space (if existence and uniqueness of EFE hold for our system). Won't solving EFE (for unique solution) always lead to the case of only one microstate?

Though I'm kind of cheating in my above reasoning as microstates and entropy need to associate only to the case of black hole or in general some event horizon. I want to know how can one try to associate different states to a given solution since to do it one needs to change some parameter in such a way that our $g_{\mu\nu}$ doesn't change (otherwise our geometry will change) but solving EFE is not possible for a general case and tweaking few input parameter will sure to give us hard time to figure out how the 10 coupled nonlinear differential equations are affected and the differential equation has to give the same solution after change in the parameters.

Comment: "if I am somehow provided with $T_{\mu\nu}$", but can you? The EFE and matter equations are coupled in general. Also do you have trouble with entropy in case of ordinary statistical physics? Since EFE will give you curvature of spacetime, but in ordinary statistical physics this is already known (it is flat) and you can imagine this to be approximate solution to EFE.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful to consider the collapse of a star into a black hole. Originally, the entropy of the star is very large because there are many configurations of its atoms.

Conversely, we know that this star must collapse into a black hole. Furthermore, because of uniqueness theorems (e.g. no hair theorem) the black hole is only described by mass, spin, and charge. The properties of the event horizon create this by not allowing the information inside the black hole to leave it.

While solving EFE for a star will give a single microstate, there is no theorems that guarantee that it is the unique solution. This is what makes black holes special.